# PHP Search by Image within website

Tags: php, search, php-gd, google-image-search

I have an eCommerce website in core PHP. I want to add search-by-image facility like google images or other reverse image search search engines.

I searched a lot on internet and I can't use google's search facility in my website (Neither `api` nor `Curl`). The main reason is that I want to search pages by Images (search result would be pages that contains images) within the website. Here is the scenario.

When a user uploads an image, the backend php will process the image and find related image that are already stored on server (Images are stored in server's directory and their filename are stored in database that is associated to a product and in turn, it will list the product that having similar product image)

I assume that first I have to process all images that are stored in server and store related pixel information in database along with filename. But I have no idea what to store in order to search later.

Comment: You cannot just search by pixels. 'Similar' is the word. If you grab your camera and make two pictures of an object, you will notice that their binary representation is completely different, even if you would compare the plain, uncompressed pixels. It takes very advanced algorithms, and a lot of time to 'teach' these algorithms. This is not something you can just build using a simple PHP script and a bunch of images in a folder.

Comment: Just finding edges in an image is a pretty advanced project in itself.

Comment: @GolezTrol. Thanks for your input. But I don't wanna compare exactly but similarly. Yes it's an advanced project but looking for ideas.

Comment: If you ever get a solution, or similar work-ground please do post here.

Answer (score 0):

to use the google's search by image, you could try reading this post:
http://www.askdavetaylor.com/how_to_add_google_images_search_my_site/

it looks like thats what you're aiming at